# Error hibernate QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, jpql

I don't see where is the error.

This is query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Sustitutos.Q_BUSCAR_SUSTITUTOS_OFICINA,
query = "select e from Sustitutos e inner join Personas p ON p.codPersona = e.sustituido WHERE p.codUnidad = :codigo"),
```

And I call it in this way:

```
        Query q = this.em.createNamedQuery(Sustitutos.Q_BUSCAR_SUSTITUTOS_ZONA);
        q.setParameter("codigo", codUnidadSup);
        List<Sustitutos> resultado = q.getResultList();
```

The stack trace:

```
Error in named query: Sustitutos.buscarSustitutosOficina
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 
1, column 83 [select e from com.bs.proteo.channel.arc.entity.Sustitutos e 
inner join Personas p ON p.codPersona = e.sustituido WHERE p.codUnidad = 
:codigo]
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: please show us the whole stack trace?

Comment: You have to join using the object references. HQL is not the same as SQL. If you need more help, soh the objects `Sustitutos` and `Personas`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `"ON"` in `JPQL`, but you can do an implicit join and use the `WHERE` clause.

```
 @NamedQuery(name = Sustitutos.Q_BUSCAR_SUSTITUTOS_OFICINA,
    query = "select e from Sustitutos e  join  e.personas p WHERE p.codUnidad = :codigo"),
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see it in the Stack trace the problem is with the `ON`keyword.

It's an **SQL** keyword and it's not recognized in **JPQL**, and as stated in comments you should join the object reference with `JOIN`.

This is how your query should be:

```
query = "select e from Sustitutos e join e.personas p WHERE p.codUnidad = :codigo")
```